# hiding html button in special scenerio

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter.

I am opening a new view `abc` from a view(calling) `xyz`.

I want to hide a button in this special case(when called/opened from view `xyz`) 
i.e in view abc.

Let me know how to do this.

This is my code for opening new view and in `url` variable I am storing that address.

```
if(url) {
   var win = window.open(url,'_blank');
   if(win){
      //Browser has allowed it to be opened
      win.focus();
   } else{
      //Broswer has blocked it
      alert('Please allow popups for this site');
   }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify that where your button exist to which you want to hide?

Comment: Also give some temporary names to your views so that we can understand it

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to use a parameter which will be sent from xyz then it will be checked in abc that if that parameter exist then button html will not be shown.

For example:

code in xyz view

```
if(url) {
   url = url+"?hidebtn=true";
   var win = window.open(url,'_blank');
   if(win){
      //Browser has allowed it to be opened
      win.focus();
   } else{
      //Broswer has blocked it
      alert('Please allow popups for this site');
   }
}
```

Now in abc view

```
<?php 
var $specialClass='';
$specialClass=$_GET["hidebtn"];
if($specialClass){
    //your code to hide button
}
?>
```